# Making YesActionBar and NoActionBar theme in Android and using them in application

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I would like to create simple activities in my android application and divide them into `no-action bar` and `action-bar` activities. To achieve this goal, I created 2 styles in `styles.xml` file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>

<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Additionally, my android manifest contains following lines of code:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

because I want to use AppTheme by default. How can I use `NoActionBar` style in my activities?

I have tried using it as: `style="@style/NoActionBar"` and `android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"` but without any success.

I would like to override default style by editing .xml files. Could you please help me with that?

My current API level is 11

Comment: @DerGolem I have already tried to do that, but without any success - Action Bar is still visible. Is there something else I can do to change it (like increasing API level)?

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer, so that you can accept it and remove this post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the ActionBar in code, by setting it invisible (well, it's really **gone**) in the `onCreate()` event of your "no-action" Activity/es.
Or in the `onCreateView()` event of your "no-action" Fragment/s.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Removing

Answer (score 0):

You can put the style in the application tag which will apply to ALL activities in the app. Then, to specify which activities use the specific themes, you can add that same line of code after each activity tag.

Or, in your class (code not xml), you can specify with:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Default method calls
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

I would also suggest using this as the parent theme instead: `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: you cannot use `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar` and appcompat stuff